# How to enable GPU in Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, pytorch, jupyter

I am trying to enable GPU in my Jupyter notebook, and I want to use pytorch to enable it.
I tried torch.cuda.is_available() and torch.cuda.current_device(), but both didn't work.

Torch cuda not found:

[image: error messga]

I have two GPUs, I have no idea why it cannot detect them.
Task manager displays I have two GPUs:

[image: GPUS]

Comment: Do you see the same in IPython console?

Comment: Yes. In Ipython console, I tried CPUtil.getAvailable() and torch.cuda.is_available(), but both returned False

Comment: Then it sounds like you have installed PyTorch without Cuda support. Check that you are following all of the required steps: https://pytorch.org/get-started/locally/

Comment: You need to install CUDA and NVIDAI Drivers